# Is there a way to make Windows 7 install .iso onto USB drive from OSX?

Tags: windows, macos, usb, installation, disk-utility

I copied my windows 7 cd to a ISO and trying to source the image onto my USB drive from OSX. So far it doesn't seem like it's possible with disk utility. Is there something else I can do to make this work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course, the command line is always there to help.

- Insert the USB flash drive and run the command `diskutil list` to find out the disk name, we'll use `/dev/disk1` as an example.
- Now unmount the disk using `diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk1`
- Now we are ready to copy the ISO to the device:

```
dd if=/path/to/Win7.iso of=/dev/disk1 bs=8192
```

Comment: Awesome, I'll try this thank you. How do I mount it though? I think you missed that... I might be confused on terminology. Don't you have to mount to copy it? Also what about NTFS?

Comment: If the disk is preformatted as NTFS it should still be able to read/write to it. You do not have to mount it as you are writing to the device.

Comment: Does not create a bootable USB drive. Wasted 2 hours of my night.

Comment: Not bootable for PC nor for Mac

Comment: Not bootable when performed with OSX 10.15.3