# What strategy should I use for two hard drives in Macbook Pro + Windows 7?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, boot-camp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I install Windows OS (Windows 7) on a removable USB hard drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/17880/can-i-install-windows-os-windows-7-on-a-removable-usb-hard-drive)
>   [Is there a way to make Windows 7 install .iso onto USB drive from OSX?](https://superuser.com/questions/244838/is-there-a-way-to-make-windows-7-install-iso-onto-usb-drive-from-osx)

I just bought a new Macbook Pro. I'm going to install a SSD (180gb) + OWC Data Doubler (750gb 5,400 rpm drive that came w/ mbp) + 16gb of ram into it.

I want the SSD to be my main drive for OSX. I want the HDD to store any large files that I don't want on the SSD for OSX.

I want to install Windows 7 (most likely) on the HDD.

Since I'm removing the optical disc, I figure my only strategy for installing Windows 7 is via USB key. This is possible, yes? If so, how?

How would you implement this strategy?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are a few links on here on how to put Windows onto a usb drive.

Answer (score 0):

[WinToFlash](http://wintoflash.com/home/en/) is a nice utility for creating a Windows installation USB drive.

Alternatively, you could actually leave the DVD drive in along with the SSD, install Windows 7 to the SSD, and then replace the DVD drive with the hard disk.

Another alternative would be to use a USB DVD drive.

Comment: I'd say this last option is the most likely.  If you are taking out the optical drive, you probably just need a SATA->USB converter, which you'll find in any SATA usb enclosure.